# Помогите переписать код(с функицями)

Tags: c, функции

Нужно сделать функцию, которая принимает на вход какое-то число не нулевых чисел(float) и возвращает число с min дробной частью.
(Чтобы было красиво, можно/нужно добавить макрос)

Вот мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int okruglenie(float a)
{
int b;

  if (a < 0)
    b = (int)a - 1;
  else
    b = (int)a;

  return b;
}

float func(float* a, int n) {
float f = 0;
float min = 0;
float j = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (a[i] == 0) break;

     f = a[i] - okruglenie(a[i]);

     if (f < j) {
        j = f;
        min = a[i];
     }

  }

return min;
}

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
float a[1000];
float val;
int i = 0;
float min = 0;

printf("Введите вещественные числа: \n");
printf("Чтобы закончить ввод-введите ноль(0) \n");

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) a[i] = 0;

i = 0;

while (scanf("%f", &val) && i < 1000) {
   if (val == 0) break;
   else a[i] = val;
   i++;
}

min = func(a, i);
printf("%.2f\n", min);
return 0;
}
```

**Пример ввода и вывода, который должен получиться:**

```
f(1.5); // == 1.5
f(1.5, 1.3); // == 1.3
```

Comment: Три вопроса: 1) Что такое oKRUKC? 2) Зачем Вам макрос? 3) Почему Вы не используете библиотечные функции округления?

Comment: 1) ошибочка, там функция okruglenie должна быть
2)Меня попросили
3)не могу по заданию

Comment: Одно небольшое замечание: в примере у Вас приведен вызов функции f. Я так понимаю, в коде ей соответствует func? Но ее сигнатура не соответствует примеру.